# Precompile Razor views when using Nancyfx

Tags: razor, nancy

Is it possible to precompile Razor views when using Nancyfx? When I attempt to do this I receive: Error ASPRUNTIME: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

I did see where someone asked this question and someone said you couldn't, but it was a couple years ago and I wanted to see if that changed.

If I can't precompile then is it difficult to try to switch from Razor to the Super Simple View Engine? With Razor when it isn't precompiled there is a performance hit during startup because it compiles it then. That is my issue I'm dealing with that I want to try to resolve.